# Purchasing a domain name and pointing to a dynamic IP

Tags: domain-name-system, ddns

I designed a small hardware device that will need to periodically check for updates over wifi. I am looking into getting a proper domain name, as currently I am using one of the free ones from noip that requires confirming every 30 days.

The free domain from noip works well as my modem/router has support for their services built in. Looking through their site, it's not immediately evident if purchasing a top level domain will allow me to have it updated when my IP changes as the free one does.

I am wondering if I am comparing apples with oranges here... Is the "free hostname" the same as a paid domain name in terms of supporting dynamic dns?

When I look into their "[enhanced dynamic dns](https://www.noip.com/remote-access)" service, I still have to pick from a list of subdomains, I can't seem to enter my own .org. Then when I click on the ["domains" service](https://www.noip.com/domains), I can enter exactly the domain name I would like.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have dynamic DNS on a custom domain. There are several services that provide dynamic DNS services. NoIP that you linked to has a services called Plus Managed DNS that does what you want.

Dynamic DNS for a custom domain requires 3 different services:

- Registrar: handles purchase and registration of a domain, holds the name server records
- Name servers: holds the DNS records for your domain
- Dynamic DNS service: updates the name servers based on certain rules (usually you current IP) - requires software running on equipment in question

NoIP provide all 3 services at a cost close to $50 a year. If NoIP already works with your modem this might be the best solution.

It is however possible to find lower cost options. CloudFlare provides a registrar service at cost price and a free DNS service with an API for updating domains. With a bit of scripting this can be set up as your own dynamic DNS at a fraction of the cost - but it will require access to run scripts on the device in question (or built in support for CloudFlare).

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you can only transfer a domain to cloudflare, they don't register yet... I'll probably go with noip for now and transfer after the first year.

Comment: There are plenty of other domain name registrars who typically charge less than a beer in your local bar, for a .com. From there is is easy to transfer it into cloudflare